# Using Django Scopes to distinguish between user and client

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am developing a REST API which is consumed by an angular js app as well as some other apps/clients. I am using Django REST Framework and I want to use django-oauth-toolkit OAUTH2 for authentication handling.

Problem:
Some of the API calls should only be callable by those other apps/clients and not by the user itself (Reason: Allow external apps to unlock achievements for a specific user but don't allow the user to do that). 
I thought of using two different scopes: one for the user and one for those external apps/clients and only allow specific API calls to either of those scopes. Is that a proper way to achieve my intent? If so, how can I restrict the user from aquiring the "external app" scope?

Comment: In theory couldn't users create their own API client and evade this extra level of "security"? The other option is to do something like check `request.token` and make sure it's attached to your website's API client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before by using a custom `Authentication` in DjangoRestFramework

```
class APIKeyAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):
        """
        Check if there is an api key in the request and match it
        to the api keys we have. If it matches or is empty allow entrance.
        """
        api_key = request.META.get('HTTP_X_APIKEY', None)
        if not api_key:
            # if api key not in headers try get params
            api_key = request.GET.get("apikey", request.GET.get("api_key", None))

        if not api_key:
            # no api key in request
            raise PermissionDenied(
                detail="No API key send. Use the header \"X-APIKey\" "
                       "or the GET parameter \"apikey\""
            )


        auth_user = get_user_from_django_oauth_toolkit()

        if api_key == settings.APIKEYS["internal"]:
            request.is_internal = True

        return auth_user, None
```

You'll need to update `settings.py` to tell DRF to use this authentication

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'app.authentication.APIKeyAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks, that seams to be nearly what I was looking for. But how do you apply this custom Authentication class to only some of my API calls? Or how does your class distinguish requests of an app or the user itself?

Comment: In my example there is a setting `settings.APIKEYS` which lists the different type of static api keys. If you also have per-user keys, then you'll need to query your data store to find out who the user is. You can add as many other properties to the request (like `request.is_a_real_human=True` or `request.has_blue_eyes=True`) so that your view code can work as required.

Comment: Does APIKey authentication use tokens?